# Searching inside files in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

Yes, I've read other similar questions and no, none of the answers work for me, so I ask again:

How do I search for a string inside ALL files in Windows 7 with indexing turned OFF? Is it possible? The string is 'support', the file is .php, I tried `support`, `php content:support`, `php contents:support`, `*.php content:support`, `*.php contents:support` and with the extension and string switched places.

I can see the file, it's right there and it has the word `support` inside, but it still says `No items match your search`

Comment: Maybe try the following from the command line, possibly an elevated command line: findstr /spin support *.php

Comment: Might help to mention *which* questions, and any obvious failure modes.

Comment: @MarkAllen That worked, but it doesn't work from Windows Explorer. When I say it doesn't work, I mean it says `No items match your search`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't more help, I don't use Windows 7 anymore so I can't check it myself.